# Local Decleration Hides Instance Variable - setting up ViewNavigation Controller

Tags: objective-c, variables, uinavigationcontroller, instance

I am converting a simple app which was only a TabViewContoller to one where I need to push multiple views via Navagation controllers.  The following Code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Create Start view controller.
    UITabBarController *rootController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *startController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];

    // Similarly create for TabBarController, ToDoController and any others over time ...
    UIViewController *ToDoViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ToDoViewController" bundle:nil];

    // Create an array of view controllers.
    NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:startController, ToDoViewController, nil];

    // Create our tab bar controller.
    self.rootController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    // Set the view controllers of the tab bar controller.
    self.rootController.viewControllers = controllers;

    // Add the tab bar controller to the window.
    [self.window addSubview:self.rootController.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Gives me two warnings and crashes when I run.  The warnings are on the Line UINavigationController and on the NSArray line.  In both cases I get the message:

Local Declaration of rootContoller hides instance variable.

here is my Header file:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface Wasted_TimeAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    UITabBarController *rootController;
    UINavigationController *startController;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *rootController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *startController;
@end
```

I am sure it has to do with the fact that I want the UITabBarContoller to be my 1st view controller in the stack.  Any suggestions on the correct way to setup this behavior?

Comment: with your current implementation, you are having UITabBarController which consists of UINavigationController which consists of a UITabBarController inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is complaining that you have a local variable with the same name as an instance variable. You also seem to have an IBOutlet on `rootViewController` and `startController`. Do you really need that?

With Objective C's automatic property synthesis you can remove your instance variable in header file. That will get rid of your warning.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface Wasted_TimeAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

// Removed IBOutlet since the view controller is created in code
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITabBarController *rootController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *startController;
@end
```

Then change your method to use the properties

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Create Start view controller.
    // PS: Using properties
    self.rootController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.startController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];

    // Similarly create for TabBarController, ToDoController and any others over time ...
    UIViewController *ToDoViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ToDoViewController" bundle:nil];

    // Create an array of view controllers.
    NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:startController, ToDoViewController, nil];

    // Create our tab bar controller.
    self.rootController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    // Set the view controllers of the tab bar controller.
    self.rootController.viewControllers = controllers;

    // Add the tab bar controller to the window.
    [self.window addSubview:self.rootController.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have an instance variable named `rootController`. Then in the code you posted, you also have a local variable named `rootController`. The warning is simply telling you that the local variable `rootController` is hiding the instance variable `rootController`. In other words, due to the local variable, you have no way to directly access the instance variable in that block of code.

This may or may not be an issue. It depends on what you need.

There are two solutions:

1) Rename the local variable to something different so it doesn't hide the instance variable.

2) Use modern Objective-C compiler features. Get rid of the instance variables used for the properties. Also get rid any explicit calls to `@synthesize`. All you need is the `@property` lines. No need to also declare the associated instance variables.

Option 2 is the better choice in this case. Then any reference to `rootController` will be to the local variable and any reference to the property will be done with `self.rootController`. You never need to directly access the instance variable (which will now be named `_rootController`).

Comment: After struggling with this for some time, I ended up refactoring my app to use a Storeboard from the original XIB based app.  During that restructioning, I removed the structure that was causing this problem. (Which basically too me down #2's path).